# How can i update an existing field in a table using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

The program i'm working on in a simple `inbound/outbound` `date/timestamp`. An entry is added to the table for an **inbound truck** then when when the truck leaves an outbound entry is added. In the outbound form is a drop down list of everything that has come inbound but not outbound. This allows the user to select which entry needs to be updated. I'm stuck trying to get the information for the outbound portion into the already created field. I was trying to edit the table only if the selected entry is equal to the id in the table. Is there something i am missing? or is there a better way to approach this?

I got the information into the table using but it doesn't update the selected record.

```
Private Sub Inbound_Click()
    Set mydb = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set Sitelog = mydb.OpenRecordset("T_Sitelog")

    Sitelog.AddNew
    Sitelog![Trailer_Type] = Me![TrailerType]
    Sitelog![Trailer_Num] = Me![TrailerNum]
    Sitelog![Carrier] = Me![Carrier]
    Sitelog![T/D_IN] = Me![TDStamp_IN]
    Sitelog![Inbound_Comments] = Me![Comments_IN]
    Sitelog.Update
End Sub

Private Sub Outbound_Click()
    Set mydb = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set Sitelog = mydb.OpenRecordset("T_Sitelog Where ID = " & _
        Me!TrailersOnProperty.Column(0))

    Sitelog.Edit
    Sitelog![T/D_OUT] = Me![TDStamp_OUT]
    Sitelog![Outbound_Comments] = Me![Comments_OUT]
    Sitelog.Update
End Sub
```

I except the result to update the already existing record added in the inbound portion. A date/timestamp and comments should be updated into the table.

Comment: It might have updated the record. You must requery the form or control displaying the data to make the changes visible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `Bound Column` property of `TrailersOnProperty` is set to `0` and then try this:

```
Private Sub Outbound_Click()
    Set mydb = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set Sitelog = mydb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM T_Sitelog WHERE ID = " & Me!TrailersOnProperty)
    Sitelog.MoveFirst
    Sitelog.Edit
    Sitelog![T/D_OUT] = Me![TDStamp_OUT]
    Sitelog![Outbound_Comments] = Me![Comments_OUT]
    Sitelog.Update
End Sub
```

You can either use a table/query name or a proper SQL query for recordsets. A table name followed by a `WHERE` clause is neither. Also there is no guarantee that when you open the recordset the cursor will be at the first record. It could easily be at `EOF`.